# TYPO3 multi language. URL back to default when no translation. How to?

Tags: typo3, multilingual

i am currently working on a project that requires two languages. For example German (L=0) and Leicht German (L=1).

My goal is, when there is a translation available on the German page to Leicht German, a button will appear and redirect the user to the Leicht German language. So far so good it works.

But, when you are on the Leicht German version and you want to move to another page where no Leicht German translation is available, by clicking on the submenu and not the button itself, the URL stays on the L=1 and it doesn't go back to L=0.

I would like your knowledge on this matter cause i am run out of ideas.

Here is my code:

```
    config {
      linkVars = L(0-1)

      uniqueLinkVars = 1

      defaultGetVars.L = 0

      sys_language_uid = 0

      sys_language_overlay = 1

      language = de

      locale_all = de-DE
    }



    [globalVar = GP:L = 1] 
    config { 
    sys_language_uid = 1 
    language = leichte Sprache 
    locale_all = de_DE.UTF-8 
    htmlTag_setParams = lang="ls" dir="ltr" class="no-js" } 
    [global]
```

This is my list where when you click you redirect to the Leicht German and backwards.

```
lib.language = COA 
lib.language {
20 = HMENU 
20 { 
special = language 
special.value = 0,1 
special.normalWhenNoLanguage = 0 
wrap = <ul class="languageMenu">|</ul> 
1 = TMENU 
1 { 
noBlur = 1 
NO = 1 
NO { 
linkWrap = <li>|</li> 
stdWrap.override = Deutsch || Leichte Sprache 
stdWrap { 
typolink { 
parameter.data = page:uid 
additionalParams = &L=0 || &L=1 
ATagParams = hreflang="de-DE" || hreflang="de-LS" 
addQueryString = 1 addQueryString.exclude = L,id,cHash,no_cache 
addQueryString.method = GET useCacheHash = 1 
no_cache = 0 
} 
} 
} 
ACT < .NO 
ACT.linkWrap = <li class="active">|</li> 
USERDEF1 < .NO 
USERDEF1 { 
linkWrap = <li class="text-muted">|</li> 
stdWrap.typolink > 
} 
} 
} 
}
```

This is the submenu where when you click and no translation is available it should redirect the user to the default language (L=0)

```
lib.subnav = HMENU 
lib.subnav.entryLevel = 1 
lib.subnav { 
1 = TMENU 
1 { 
wrap = <ul class="side-nav">|</ul> 
noBlur = 1 
NO = 1 
NO { 
wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li> 
ATagTitle.field = title 
typolink { 
parameter.data = page:uid 
additionalParams = &L=0 || &L=1 
ATagParams = hreflang="de-DE" || hreflang="de-LS" 
addQueryString = 1 addQueryString.exclude = L,id,cHash,no_cache
 addQueryString.method = GET 
useCacheHash = 1 
no_cache = 0 
} 
} 
ACT < .NO ACT { 
ATagParams = class="active" wrapItemAndSub = <li class="active">|</li> 
} 
}
```

At this point i have nothing else to add. If you need more from me, feel free to ask.

Thanks in advance,

Aris

Comment: why do you care what the url says, this is the behaviour of TYPO3, it remains with L=1 unless otherwise selected but serves the default language if no translation available ...

Answer (score 0):

did you try this, just let typo3 take care of the link:

```
lib.subnav = COA
lib.subnav {
    10 = HMENU
    10 {
        entryLevel = 1
        1 = TMENU
        1 {
            expAll = 1
            wrap = <ul class="side-nav">|</ul>
            noBlur = 1
            NO = 1
            NO {
                wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
                ATagParams = title="{field:title}"
                ATagParams.insertData = 1
            }
            ACT < .NO
            ACT {
                wrapItemAndSub = <li class="active">|</li>
                ATagParams = class="active"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: no this is for the content. Not for the URL. I tried it but it didnt work. I should have mentioned it, i am sorry.

Comment: which version of typo3 do you use ? this is the first time I see the language defined in a menu other then the language switch ... you did try a submenu without any of the language stuff inserted, I do a lot of multi language but it gets added by typo3, that might be your problem ... you overwrite typo3 ...